# send users to another page if landed on wrong one

Tags: php

I rewrote my search url from this

```
domain.com/search.php?q=query&search=1
```

to

```
domain.com/search.php?q=query&select=all
```

"query = search term". How can I send someone to the select=all page if they landed on search=1?
I have a ton of google links with search=1 and am trying to reroute users and at the same time get google to remove the parameter and index select=all.
This is what I am doing right now and it sends people to the homepage if they land on a search=1 and I don't like doing that.

```
if (empty($_GET['select']))
header("Location: http://domain.com/");
```

Does anyone have any suggestions? thanks.

Comment: "don't like" is not an explanation.

Comment: I explained it. If a user lands on a search=1 page it redirects them to the homepage.

Comment: basically if select is not a paramter it sends them to the homepage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (!isset($_GET['select']))
{
    header("Location: http:///search.php?q=".$_GET['q']."&select=all");
}
```

**EDIT**
By the way, if you need to remove a URL from Google's index, you can submit it at https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/removals?pli=1

Also, you can submit your new url to the Google index at http://www.google.com/addurl/?continue=/addurl

Answer (score 0):

```
if(empty($_GET['select')){
    header ('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
    header ('Location: http://domain.com'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?q='.$_GET['q'].'&select=all');
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't use empty in this scenario. empty($_GET['select') will evaluate to true if the value of $_GET['select'] is 0 or FALSE or anything like that. Better is to use isset()